# get commit SHA in aws CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab, xcodebuild, aws-codebuild

I have a ci cd process that starts at GitLab, pack to latest commit to zip and upload it to AWS S3.
That triggers a AWS Pipeline source stage, that trigger CodeBuild and later CodeDeploy.
During that process I want to push docker images to AWS ECS, and tag them with the commit SHA short version.
I do not see a way to pass that from Gitlab to CodeBuild, is there a "correct" way to achieve it?
Thanks

Comment: I can think about of one workaround, you can add commit id SHA in one file and also push that file in S3 and read the file content in code pipeline and use it during code build to tag image with commit id

Comment: @DeepakGupta The only place I can see where I can add it is in the gitlab-ci.yml (or any scripts run by it), and then I need again to commit that file, and it would trigger the CI actions all over again.

Comment: EDIT: it is possible: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2496 :) thanks man